# How to Identify which person with root access has killed a job/process from a pool

Tags: linux, unix

I was curious to know if there are 3 or 4 people who has root access to a node. one of the person has initiated a job for running, But some one has killed the job that was running. what would be the best way to identify the person who killed the job/process because every body has root access.

Comment: Probably better for superuser.com

Comment: also posted in superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

bash_history. I admit that maybe there's better way.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the process accounting records (e.g. with `lastcomm`) to see the job was in fact killed by a signal, and if so then check for use of the `kill` command at exactly that time and see what tty it was run on, then look through the `last` output to see who was logged in on that terminal.   What you don't have process accounting enabled?  Go back in time and turn on process accounting!  :-) (IMNSHO process accounting should always be on and working on any type of production, development, or test system.)